# Thanking two parties seperately. Should i use "on the part of"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I'm writing my acknowledgements for my thesis. The thesis was created in addition to my work at a company for this company and submitted at my university. I've had help from both, workers from the company as well as the specific institute from the university.

The ackowledgements would start as follows:

> This diploma thesis was created in addition to my student work at Big Company X and submitted at the Institute for random things at one of the universities in this city.

Then i would like to acknowledge the contribution of workers from the institute. In german i would use "Seitens" which translates to "on the part of" in english. Therefore i would write:

> On the part of the institute i would like to thank Prof. A and Prof. B.....

In a similar manner i would thank specific persons from the company:

> On the part of Big Company X i would like to thank Mr. Y and Mr. Z.....

Is this the correct usage of "on the part of"?
Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: It’s hard to take this question seriously when you won’t even capitalize “I”. Would you spell it in lower-case in your thesis?

Comment: Neither "I" nor "i" are written anywhere in the thesis besides the acknowledgements. The same acknowledgments i'm trying to improve by posting here. Thanks for belittling a non native speaker in a community called "English Language Learners".

Comment: You can take it as “belittling”. I meant it as [constructive criticism](http://www.definitions.net/definition/constructive%20criticism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would normally just use "at" or "from."

Let's try and do a little rewriting:

> Work on this thesis was supported by Big Company X and by the Institute for random things at one of the universities in this city.

I know this is quite a change from what you wrote, but it needed a lot of revision.

If you forced me to keep the same structure as you have, I would say

> At the institute, I would like to thank Prof A and Prof B.

However, it would personally write something like

> I would like to thank Professor A and Professor B from the institute of random things, whose insightful comments...

And then in the next paragraph

> I have also benefited greatly from the guidance and support offered by Mr. Y and Mr. Z at Big Company X.

I suppose using "on the part of" is not grammatically wrong, but no native speaker would use it in this context.